# How to load different part of data from JSON file for each page using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I'm trying to create a shopping website using angularJs. My website has several html pages like women.html, men.html,...

I has 1 JSON file for the whole website. I want each website has different products, I did it but it only works on the main page (the page which showing all the products). When I click on a specific product, it doesn't show anything thing.

For more clearly, here is my code:

JSON file:

```
 {
  "Men": [
 {
  "name": "Adidas",
  "price": 20,
  "id": "adidas1",
  "image": "pic4.png",
  "description": "abcđsfadfdfsgsg"
},
{
  "name": "Nike",
  "price": 37,
  "id": "nike1",
  "image": "pic2.png",
  "description": "abcđsfadfdfsgsg"
},
{
  "name": "Converse",
  "price": 25,
  "id": "converse1",
  "image": "pic3.png",
  "description": "abcđsfadfdfsgsg"
}
],
"Women": [
 {
   "name": "Adidas2",
  "price": 20,
  "id": "adidas2",
  "image": "pic6.png",
  "description": "abcđsfadfdfsgsg"
 },
 {
  "name": "Nike2",
  "price": 37,
  "id": "nike2",
  "image": "pic7.png",
  "description": "abcđsfadfdfsgsg"
 },
 {
  "name": "Converse2",
  "price": 25,
  "id": "converse2",
  "image": "pic5.png",
  "description": "abcđsfadfdfsgsg"
 }
 ]
 }
```

Men.html:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items.Men" style="float:left;">
    <div><a href="#/item/{{item.name}}"><img src="/image/{{item.image}}" />
</a>
</div>
    </div>
```

Women.html:

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in items.Women" style="float:left;">
    <div>
        <a href="#/item/{{item.name}}"><img src="/image/{{item.image}}" />
</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

App.js:

```
app.controller('ItemCtrl',
['$scope', '$routeParams', 'cartService',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, cartService) {
        $scope.item = {};
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
            if (item.name == $routeParams.itemName) {
                $scope.item.itemName = item.name;
                $scope.item.itemPrice = item.price;
                $scope.item.itemId = item.id;
                $scope.item.itemImage = item.image;
                $scope.item.itemDescription = item.description;
            }
        });

        $scope.addProduct = function (item) {

            cartService.addToCart(item, $scope.numberOfProducts);

        };

    }
]);
```

Product details page:

```
<div style="float:left; margin:0px 50px 300px 50px;">
<img src="/image/{{item.itemImage}}" style="margin- bottom:50px;margin-
left:200px;">
<p style="margin-right:0px;margin-top:50px;margin-left:50px;">Description:
{{item.itemDescription}}</p>
    </div>
```

The code is really long so I only show its parts which I think making my code doesn't work.

Hopefully, there would be some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check whether 'ItemCtrl' controller is binded to both men.html and women.html, if both the html files are not views.

Answer (score 1):

Make two controllers and use $http method to call each page.Then using scope,reference data that you want and render in each page